# How can I put two arguments in one string for a input function in python?

Tags: python, string

I am pretty new to python and am trying to create a small game just to help develop my skills, but I ran in to one code line I just can't figure out.

```
r = str(input("Player 1 please enter a integer between 1 and 10: "))
```

I have another line that goes earlier and asks the player for a name.

`name = input('Player 1 what is your name? ')`

but I want it so that instead of it saying

`r = str(input("Player 1 please enter a integer between 1 and 10: "))`

that it says the name of the player I got from the input earlier on in the code?
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [formated string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting):

```
r = str(input("%s please enter a integer between 1 and 10: " % player_name))
```

`input` expects a string. So, first you construct a approprate string and then pass it. Simplified example of `%`

```
"%s is good" % "he" # transforms to "he is good"
```

`%` It is a sort of substitution operation with type checking, eg.`%s` specifies string type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting for this.

```
r = str(input("%s please enter a integer between 1 and 10: " % name))
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you use (according to [PEP-3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/))  :

```
r = str(input('{} please enter a integer between 1 and 10: '.format(name)))
```

Instead of using the modulo operator (%) like :

```
r = str(input("%s please enter a integer between 1 and 10: " % name))
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111630/how-to-mark-a-question-on-so-as-resolved

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this since you are working with integers:

However, this solution will only work in Python 2

```
player_name = raw_input("What is your name")
r = int(input("%s Enter a number:" % player_name))
```